# Is it possible to declare functional dependencies among non-primary keys in a single table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, functional-dependencies

Let's assume a functional dependency: `R(A,B,C,D) & FDs{ A->B, A->C, (B,C)->D }`

`A` can identify any tuple. Defining `A` as a primary key, we can implement the dependency hold between `A` and others. But the combination of `B` & `C` can also uniquely identify `D`.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
    `A` INT NOT NULL ,
    `B` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
    `C` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
    `D` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`A`) 
);
```

This SQL only contains the dependency between `A` and others. But this SQL does not say that `B,C` can also uniquely identify `D`.
Is it possible to define the dependency between `B,C` and `D` using a single table in MySQL?

I think one way is to use another table. One table for `R(A,B,C) & FDs{ A->B, A->C }`. And another table for `R(B,C,D) & FDs{ (B,C)->D }`. However, I would like to use a single table.

Comment: Is this valid:  `name = CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname)`?  If so, then you should not be storing `name`.  It is a no-no in databases to have redundant information.

Comment: @RickJames, yes. `name = CONCAT(fname, '  ', lname)`. But let assume `name != CONCAT(fname, '  ', lname)` for this question. So how can I do this?

Comment: @RickJames, I need to know this because I read in [Detection of Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) that the column functionally dependent of the `GROUP BY` column can be projected using SELECT. They gave the examples using joining two tables. I was wondering if I can do this on a single table.

Comment: Still not clear. Still images. What does "implement the dependency" mean? Declare it in SQL? PS SQL has poor constraint declaration ability. Your table is poorly designed, it is not in 2NF, so it is hard to constrain in SQL. Learn about DB normalization. Follow a textbook on information modeling & DB design & ask a question where you are 1st stuck/unsure. Write about FDs the way you see them written about in a textbook. SQL language manuals are not textbooks on design or languages.

Comment: Now it seems clear. PS Re "I think one way is to use another table." That;s poor phrasing, because using 2 tables isn't an answer to the question that the rest of the post asks. PS Translating to your original example using first/last/full name as B/C/D, not only does BC-> hold but also D->B & D->C also hold here. So you really aren't addressing all the problems or appropriate solutions. I'll also now post another standard comment of mine regarding that. You really should follow a textbook.

Comment: Your "I have these FDs" doesn't make sense. "These are all the FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are all the non-trivial FDs that hold"?--Not possible. "These are some FDs that hold"?--Question can't be answered. Find out what a *cover* is & what the exact conditions are to apply a particular definition/rule/algorithm. To determine CKs & NFs we must be given FDs that form a cover. Sometimes a minimal/irreducible cover. And the set of all attributes must be given.

Answer (score 1):

If `ssn` is the `PRIMARY KEY`, then `GROUP BY` should be happy.  Please provide the SQL that is giving you trouble, plus the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Is this valid:  `name = CONCAT(fname, ' ', lname)`?  If so, then you should not be storing `name`.  It is a no-no in databases to have redundant information.

You could have a virtual "generated" column instead of an actual `name` column.